# Display info from database only on condition

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Working with PHP and SQL here.

I have a bridging table in my database that has columns with separate options (option 1, option 2, etc) and another table with the information of each option. This is because the result may produce one or more of these different options, or none, so I want to pull the options only if it applies.

(To explain some context, basically its about travel and theres different travel options depending on the journey for the user to choose from and thats what I want to display.)

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM route,
             option
        WHERE (
               (route.Option_1 > 0) OR (route.Option_2 > 0)
              )
              AND
              (
               (route.Option_1 == option.No) OR (route.Option_2 == option.No)
              )";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$rows = $db->executeSQL($stmt);
foreach ($rows AS $row): 
    $Option_Description = $row["Description"];
    ?> 
    <p><?php echo $Option_Description ?></p> 
    <?php
endforeach;
```

So Option_1 and Option_2 would have the numbers 1,2,3,4 etc depending on the corresponding option ID number from the options table (some journeys will display the same information but the combination may be different for example 2 and 4 for one journey and 2 and 3 for another, or just 2). But if its 0, there is no option and no information will display. So I tried to make the query so that if the number entered is > 0 then it would pull the rows of that ID and display the information otherwise returns false. But this code caused an error when I added two == marks though it was also not working when I wrote just one = mark either (was just assigning route.Option1/2 to option.No I'm pretty sure). What might be a better way to write this query to get the result I'm after?

Comment: `==` is not an operator in SQL. The `=` is the operator. Also not clear how `$pdo` is configured but that `executeSQL()` seems wrong.

Comment: You should not have 90s ansi joins. Define your joins with `join` and `on` for how the data should be join. e.g. `select from route as r join option as o on r.some_column = o.somerelatedcolumn`

Comment: [Why does SQL not use double equal (==) to mean 'A is equal to B'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67327498/2943403)

Comment: It would be much easier to understand the problem with a runnable SQL fiddle demo with sample data and an exact desired output from that sample.  We love a good [mcve].  Just eyeballin' your SQL, why not `option.No IN (route.Option_1, route.Option_2)`

Comment: @user3783243 $pdo is part of a function used to connect to the database and the way I have written it using executeSQL() is how I was taught in my web dev course but if theres a better way to do it I would be open to learning. I will try using Join and On in my query instead, thanks

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for the link. I will try to use a runnable SQL fiddle demo instead next time. I will try out your method using In thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like a PHP problem, but a pure SQL problem.  The sooner you give us a solid [mcve] and SQL demo, the sooner we can give you awesome support.  The next step is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query has issues, for example `==` is not the correct operator to compare in SQL; it should be `=`. Here is the modified SQL, try it.

```
SELECT route.*, option.*
FROM route
LEFT JOIN option AS option1 ON route.Option_1 = option1.No AND route.Option_1 > 0
LEFT JOIN option AS option2 ON route.Option_2 = option2.No AND route.Option_2 > 0
WHERE route.Option_1 > 0 OR route.Option_2 > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT opt.Description
        FROM route r
        LEFT JOIN option opt ON (r.Option_1 = opt.No OR r.Option_2 = opt.No)
        WHERE r.Option_1 > 0 OR r.Option_2 > 0";
```

Can you try this query?

**Update**

- `LEFT JOIN` is used. This ensures that all records from the route table are included, even if there's no matching record in the option table. If a `route` doesn't have a valid option (i.e., `Option_1` or `Option_2` is 0), it still appears in the result set, but with a `NULL` Description.
- **Condition in JOIN**: The condition (`r.Option_1 = opt.No OR r.Option_2 = opt.No`) ensures that the options are joined correctly based on the No field.
- **WHERE Clause**: This filters out routes where both options are 0.

Comment: Updated. But can you please upvote it back?

Comment: @DarkBee. The other answer is also does not have any detailed understanding. why are you targeting me?